# Error 401 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, http-status-code-401, c#-5.0

I'm working on my first app for Windows 8 but I have a problem, when I'm launch my app, I've got the error "Response status code does not indicate success:

> 401 (Authorization Required)

So yes, I need to include username and password but I don't know where in my code:

```
var fond = new HttpClient();
var reponse = await fond.GetStreamAsync("http://example.com/search/mario%20kart" + TitleNewsGrid.Text);
```

So where I'm include the username and password in the code?

Comment: Check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes It seems an issue related to the authorization of the web server!

Comment: @iSamnium The OP understands what the error is, they are asking how to pass credentials to the server not what the status code represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a `Credentials` property in the `TransportSettings` e.g.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.TransportSettings.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
    ...
}
```

If you don't have access to the `TransportSettings` property, you will need to use `HttpClientHandler` instead. No point in duplicating code, there is already a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292730/httpclient-getasync-with-network-credentials).

Comment: Notice the use of the using statement, which causes the client to get automatically disposed when it leaves the scope.

Comment: Hey :) Thanks for your help. For the moment i use:  System.Net.Http.HttpClient Fond = new HttpClient(); 
But TransportSettings don't use System.Net.Http.HttpClient... So I'm a little missed ^^'

Comment: @GuillaumeFortunier did you find the `TransportSettings` property?

Comment: private async void PremierTest()
        {
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
            {
                handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("appendr", "e32!cdf");
                    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler){})
                    {
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient Fond = new HttpClient();
                        var reponse = await
                Fond.GetStreamAsync("http://ws.jeuxvideo.com/search/mario%20kart" + TitleNewsGrid.Text);
but block at Fond.GetStreamAsync

Comment: Sounds like you may be hitting a deadlock in your code. Try the solution provided [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895048/async-call-with-await-in-httpclient-never-returns) and I would recommend reading the answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343632/httpclient-getasync-never-returns-when-using-await-async/10351400#10351400) as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
client.TransportSettings.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

for more info 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx