# System.Net.Http.HttpClient does not contain a definitions for TransportSettings

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I've got a problem. For beginning, this is my code:

```
HttpClient fond = new HttpClient();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpClient.TransportSettings.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
}
var reponse = await fond.GetStreamAsync("" + TitleNewsGrid.Text);
```

For me everything is OK but (sorry It's my first app ^^') when I'm compile I found this error:

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'TransportSettings'

Comment: Is it WCF? Can you give more details?

Comment: XAML C# for Windows 8 (Metro APP) so I think yes ;)

Comment: Check this, it may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292730/httpclient-getasync-with-network-credentials

Comment: Don't help me ^^' Where I'm type my username and password ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler()) 
{
    handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd");
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler){  })
    { 
        // code
    } 
}
```

Not tested ;)

Comment: 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient Fond = new HttpClient();
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pwd") })
                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
            var reponse = await
                Fond.GetStreamAsync("test"+ TitleNewsGrid.Text);
            {'

Comment: I don't find any problem in it. But I am not sure ;)

Comment: Don't work :/ it say Can not initialize type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: This is my code
    private async void PremierTest()
        {
            HttpClientHandler welcome = new HttpClientHandler();
            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("appandr", "e32!cdf") })
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                System.Net.Http.HttpClient Fond = new HttpClient();
                var reponse = await
                    Fond.GetStreamAsync("http://ws.jeuxvideo.com/search/mario%20kart" + TitleNewsGrid.Text);