# Consume WebAPI with login credential

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call a webapi from C#, the webapi is hosted in IIS and requires login when you access it.

I don't know how to call the webapi with current login credential, and if I don't pass anything, the result will be the HTML for the login page.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync("url").Result;                    
    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

I remember there is a way to pass in the current login credential, but i can't seem to find it.

Comment: BTW, the twice calling of `.Result` on those async methods may lead to errors. Better use [AsyncBridge](https://github.com/tejacques/AsyncBridge) instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpClient.GetAsync with network credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10292730/httpclient-getasync-with-network-credentials)

Comment: What authentication method is the api?

Comment: What is the controller action, that You try to call? Is it gest / post? Does it have any parameters?

Comment: You should figure out more details on how the protection works, i.e. do you need to send a cookie, a token, etc, and how do you obtain them. There is no "common way" of providing login.

Comment: It's a GET method, and there is no Authentication for the API other than it's hosted in a site that requires login