# httpclient c# couchdb unauthorized to create database

Tags: c#, couchdb

I have this code below code to create a database in couchDB:

```
private async void DatabaseCreate()
        {
            if (!await DatabaseExist())
            {
                var contents = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"); 
                this.uri = "http://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/item_sn";
                var response = await client.PutAsync(this.uri, contents); //set the contents to null but same response.
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStrifngAsync().Result); 
            }
        }
```

My problem is that it is giving me a response with StatusCode:401, saying "Unauthorized". I tried **curl**ing it in the terminal and it gives me a successful response. Is there some preconditions I need to set for the httpclient? Or am I using the wrong method. I know there are some third party package for couchDB but for my case I just want to use C#'s httpclient.

Thanks in advance

curl command:

```
curl -X PUT http://USER:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/item_sn
```

Comment: Can you provide your `curl` command?

Comment: Added my curl command to original post. Cheers.

Comment: If you do a `GetAsync("http://localhost:5984/")` operation, will you get the CouchDB welcome message? Welcome message should be like: `{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"2.1.1","features":["scheduler"],"vendor":{"name":"The Apache Software Foundation"}}`

Comment: Yes. GetAsync(uri) gives me a welcome response from couchdb. Just to add, I have no issues adding/revising  documents in an existing database with PutAsync(uri, contents) and PostAsync(uri, contents) operations. My issue is only when creating new database on couchdb. CouchDB version is 2.1.1 if that helps.

Comment: Is your username/password at CouchDB-level or at database-level?

Comment: Hmmm! Not so sure. I just configured it with a single node setup. Is there anything I need to do in the configuration? Would that matter when using c# httpclient? Because curling it seems to work. Cheers

Comment: Can you create any arbitrary database with the `curl` command?

Comment: Yes, with curl command I have no problem creating arbitrary databases. When I run your code above, I get this error: {"error":"not_found","reason":"no such node: couchdb@127.0.0.1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in HttpClient class you can include credentials with [HttpClientHandler Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with its [Credentials property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx). Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292758/3405291). Try it, maybe that would work.

Comment: `var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("USER:PASS");
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));`

Adding the lines of code before sending the request works. Thanks for the guidance mate. Appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that worked.

```
public async void DatabaseCreate()
            {
                if (!await DatabaseExist())
                {
                    var contents = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
                    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
                    this.uri = "http://localhost:5984/databasename";
                    var response = await client.PutAsync(this.uri, contents);
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); 
                }
            }
```